# aspectToFit, как получить размер изображения?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Есть UIImageView в котором установлен мод aspectToFit. Как получить размер подогнанного под размер вьюхи изображения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо его вычислить из размеров `UIImage` и `UIImageView`:

```
@IBOutlet var ivToGetSize: UIImageView! //UIImageView с искомой картинкой

//по нажатию на кнопку определяем размер картинки
@IBAction func btnClick(sender: UIButton) {
    let image = ivToGetSize.image
    if let im = image {
        let displayedSize = getDisplayedSize(im.size, imageViewBoundsSize: ivToGetSize.bounds.size)
        let imWidth = displayedSize.width
        let imHeight = displayedSize.height
        print("\(imWidth) \(imHeight)") //выводим полученные ширину и высоту картинки
    }
}

//функция для определения размера
func getDisplayedSize(imageSize: CGSize, imageViewBoundsSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
{
    var imageDisplayedSize = CGSizeMake(imageViewBoundsSize.width, imageViewBoundsSize.height);
    let mW = imageViewBoundsSize.width / imageSize.width;
    let mH = imageViewBoundsSize.height / imageSize.height;
    if( mH < mW ) {
        imageDisplayedSize.width = mH * imageSize.width;
    }
    else if( mW < mH ) {
        imageDisplayedSize.height = mW * imageSize.height;
    }
    return imageDisplayedSize;
}
```